# Standard deviation of a set of data {0,1,2,3,4} with probability

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

A random variable W can take on values in {0,1,2,3,4} with the probabilities: $$P(W=0) = 0.5\\P(W=1) = 0.1\\ P(W=2) = 0.2\\ P(W=3) = 0.15\\ P(W=4) = 0.05\\$$
I am interested in finding the standard deviation of W.

I have two ways to calculate the standard deviation, either:$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{(x-\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$$

or $$\sigma = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2 P(X=x_{i})}$$
But I cannnot get the right answer to choose. The correct answer is 1.31 while I got 1.57. Why is that?
Thank you!

Comment: The first one with an $n-1$ in the denominator is the _sample standard deviation_, which is not the right thing to compute when you know the entire probability distribution. Can you explain _how_ you get $1.57$? When I use the second formula I do indeed get $1.31$.

Comment: Yes. I calculated the mean $\mu = \frac{0+1+2+3+4}{5} = 2$. Then I plug each data point into the second formula with respect to its probability, then I've got: $\sigma = \sqrt{(0-2)^2P(W=0) + (1-2)^2P(W=1) + (2-2)^2P(W=2) +(3-2)^2P(W=3) +(4-2)^2P(W=4) }$.

Comment: Your calculation of $\mu$ is wrong -- it doesn't use the probabilities you're given but assumes they are all $\frac15$.

Comment: Omg I am so silly. Thank you. $\mu = \sum{(x_{i} - \bar{x})P(X=x_{i})}$. Thank you, Henning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of $\mu$ as $\frac{0+1+2+3+4}{5}$ is wrong. It doesn't use the probabilities you're given but instead assumes that all $5$ values are equally likely.

The actual mean is $1.15$.

Comment: @Hugh: If this resolves your question, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the green-outlined checkmark under the vote buttons. That will tell other users that the question does not need their attention.